How to factor out code into methods in a Ruby script while retaining access to the outer scope?
Suppose I have a Ruby script like the following to generate YAML describing a list of services:
require 'yaml'

environment_slug = ENV.fetch('CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG')

YAML.dump([
  {
    'name' => 'service1',
    'url' => "https://service1.#{environment_slug}.example.com",
  },
  {
    'name' => 'service2',
    'url' => "https://service2.#{environment_slug}.example.com",
  },
], STDOUT)

Now I want to factor out the generation of the service description. The following naive attempt doesn’t work because environment_slug is a local variable of the outer scope and therefore not available inside the service method:
require 'yaml'

environment_slug = ENV.fetch('CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG')

def service(name)
  {
    'name' => name,
    'url' => "https://#{name}.#{environment_slug}.example.com",
  }
end

YAML.dump([
  service('service1'),
  service('service2'),
], STDOUT)

One possible solution would be to use define_method:
require 'yaml'

environment_slug = ENV.fetch('CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG')

define_method :service do |name|
  {
    'name' => name,
    'url' => "https://#{name}.#{environment_slug}.example.com",
  }
end

YAML.dump([
  service('service1'),
  service('service2'),
], STDOUT)

However, it seems to me like define_method is a rather low-level functionality.
Another possible solution would be to use constants:
require 'yaml'

ENVIRONMENT_SLUG = ENV.fetch('CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG')

def service(name)
  {
    'name' => name,
    'url' => "https://#{name}.#{ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}.example.com",
  }
end

YAML.dump([
  service('service1'),
  service('service2'),
], STDOUT)

For consistency, I would probably make every top-level variable (in a more complex example) a constant. However, typing all-caps is rather unergonomic and doesn’t look nice if used for every “variable”.
What would be a good strategy when writing scripts that produces idiomatic Ruby code and doesn’t require me to write a lot of boilerplate for small scripts or restructure everything when things get more complex?

Another option that is technically available is the use of an instance variable @environment_slug. That being said OO design is an intrinsic fundamental principle of Ruby, so why not encapsulate the necessary logic in a class (or module), rather than building it into the script and polluting the Object class?

I would avoid define_method, it's a bit hacky and metaprogramming can make the code harder to read. Honestly if you want the easiest solution, just use constants. They're not that unergonomic or ugly, and they serve the purpose. You can use sprintf if you want but I think you might be overcomplicating things.

Why don't you moving reading the ENV into the method or pass environment_slug as an argument to the method?

Instance Variables, Accessors, and Interpolation
You can solve this in a lot of different ways, but IMHO the best is to wrap it in a class and use the accessor to call Service#environment_slug. You could also modify the value of the "url" key to render the instance variable @environment_slug instead, but that's largely a matter of taste and programmer intent.
require "yaml"

class Service
  attr_reader :environment_slug

  def initialize
    @environment_slug = ENV.fetch("CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG")
  end

  def service(name)
    {
      "name" => name,
      "url" => "https://#{name}.#{environment_slug}.example.com",
    }
  end

  # Send your YAML to standard output and also return a value.
  # Kernel#p will quote the output, so it costs you an extra
  # line in your method to do them as separate operations.
  def print
    puts yml = [service('service1'), service('service2')].to_yaml
    yml
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  # Avoid KeyError when testing, or set a sensible default for
  # ENV#fetch in your code above.
  ENV["CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG"] = "foo"

  Service.new.print
end

This will print the following to standard output:
---
- name: service1
  url: https://service1.foo.example.com
- name: service2
  url: https://service2.foo.example.com

It will also return a value, which is often a good idea for testing or chained methods:

"---\n- name: service1\n  url: https://service1.foo.example.com\n- name: service2\n  url: https://service2.foo.example.com\n"

